# R 3.5.0 not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, 18.04, r

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my testbed laptop. Total fresh install (chose the 'minimal' option). The first two things I did were install `R 3.5` and `R Studio 1.1.453`. If I open up a fresh install of R and just let it sit idle for 30 minutes or so I eventually get the error `"Error: Unable to establish connection with R session"`.

At this point in time I can't do anything in `R Studio` and I have to `xkill` it and reload everything to continue programming. An internet search reveals that this issue has been popping up repeatedly since people have been installing `R/R Studio` on Ubuntu machines that use GNOME. Am not sure if GNOME is the root cause but it's interesting.

**Anybody solved this?** Or maybe you run R 3.5 fine on Ubuntu 18.04 without issue. Please let me know. I can only run for 30 minutes or so before this issue brings my system down. And my system is a fresh install of Bionic Beaver with just R on it. Weird.

**------ and for those wondering ------**

*installation for R was via*

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

*and R Studio was installed via this link through the Ubuntu software center*
https://download1.rstudio.org/rstudio-xenial-1.1.453-amd64.deb

*and it is speculated that the preview release of R Studio may fix this (TBD)*
https://s3.amazonaws.com/rstudio-ide-build/desktop/trusty/amd64/rstudio-1.2.792-amd64.deb

Comment: R in Ubuntu 18.04 currently is  at version 3.4.4. You likely installed from another source?

Comment: @vanadium I installed from here https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/bionic-cran35/ using `sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/"` then `sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev`. I installed the keys as well prior.

Comment: OK, please add to your question because this is essential information. My version from the standard Ubuntu PPA works fine. Also indicate how you installed R studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently [CRAN mirror](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html) provides R 3.6 by default.

To get R 3.5 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS we need to add CRAN repository with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/"
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
```

and then adjust APT to the highest priority of R 3.5.x versions for the CRAN repository with long single command:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-r35
Package: r-*
Pin: release a=bionic-cran35
Pin: version 3.5*
Pin-Priority: 800

Package: r-cran-nlme
Pin: release a=bionic-cran35
Pin: version 3.1.139-1bionic0
Pin-Priority: 800

Package: r-cran-cluster
Pin: release a=bionic-cran35
Pin: version 2.0.8-1bionic0
Pin-Priority: 800
EOF
```

Then install R 3.5 with the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

And finally check that R version is 3.5:

> ```
> $ R
>
> R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
> ```

---

Notes:

1. I have checked this method on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM with two essential R packages installed - `r-base` and `r-base-dev` (and their dependencies).
2. If you want to revert to R 3.6 - then simply remove pin/lock file with `sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-r35` and run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the newest dependencies.
3. For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS the method is very similar - see [my other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1145758/66509).

Comment: I ended up installing the preview version 1.2.792 of R Studio and the issue has gone away. https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/preview/

Comment: To solve "depends on r-recommended (= 3.5.3-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed" with the instructions above I needed to add "Package: r-cran-cluster
Pin: release a=bionic-cran35
Pin: version 2.0.8-1bionic0
Pin-Priority: 800"

Comment: @krassowski thank you very much! I approved your edit.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I *did* follow your steps.  I "cleaned" my system
to the best of my abilities (as previously described; see below) and then did

```
sudo apt-get install r-base
```

This seemed (as I previously said on the Ubuntu Mate Community list,
from which you told me to switch the discussion to this location) to run without complaint, but produced no executable.

I tried

```
dpkg -l | grep "^ii -r"
```

just now, following your example, and got no output whatever.  So
it would seem that "dpkg" thinks that r-base has not been installed.

But the output from "sudo apt-get install r-base" seems to say that
it *has* been installed.  What is going on?

Added:  I have solved the problem.  Elsewhere it was suggested to me that
I try doing

dpkg -l r-base-core

This produced the enlightening output:

```
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-  pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name             Version       Architecture  Description
+++-================-=============-=============-======================================
ii  r-base-core      3.5.2-1bionic amd64         GNU R core of statistical computation
```

The nature of the message prompted me to try

```
sudo apt purge r-base-core
```

which ran and said that it was removing a whole lot of stuff.

I then tried

```
 sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

which ran and gave a whole lot more output than was previously produced when I ran "sudo apt-get install r-base".  (Note: I had been typing
*r-base* and NOT *r-base-core*.)  It indicated that it was doing lots of stuff that looked promising in respect of actually *installing* R.

And in fact the promise was fulfilled.  I then started R and got:

```
R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20) -- "Eggshell Igloo"
Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

Ta-da!!!

The problem may have been that previously I had been saying

"sudo apt-get install r-base" rather than

"sudo apt-get install r-base-core".

It is possible that the latter is needed if R has previously been installed from source, but otherwise just "r-base" is sufficient.  I am not sufficiently knowledgeable to say.  Others may be able to provide insight.