# Cannot upgrade R

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, r

My system:
Ubuntu 18.04.4

```
Rscript --version
R scripting front-end version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
```

My problem:
Unsuccessful in upgrading [R](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/R.1.html).

Steps:

```
sudo apt-get remove r-base r-base-dev
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/'
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9 (as instructed here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)
sudo apt update
sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

Output:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 r-base-core : Depends: libreadline6 (>= 6.0) but it is not installable
```

When trying to install [libreadline6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreadline6) I get:

```
sudo apt install libreadline6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libreadline6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libreadline6' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Maybe you should have removed `r-base-core` (as well as `r-base r-base-dev`)? I'm guessing you still have `r-base-core` version 3.4.4 (which wants libreadline6) whereas the new bionic-cran35 version probably wants libreadline7

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R 3.5.0 not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056630/r-3-5-0-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 0):

A search with [man libreadline6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreadline6) shows you need to install [libreadline-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libreadline-dev) as [libreadline6](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libreadline6) in Bionic (18.04) is a virtual package.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out libreadline6 is not available on Ubuntu Bionic (18.04)
So I had to get it from Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

For that I went here:
https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libreadline6
You get a list of options for libreadline6 for various architectures: amd64, i386, etc.

To find out which is your architecture, run the command:

```
 uname -m
```

In my case, because this command returned x86_64, I went for:
libreadline6_6.3-8ubuntu2_amd64.deb

Once you click on the link, it takes you to another page. 
Search there for "Binary Package" in that page.
It will display a link to a a deb package. Choose Open with "Software install (default)" and the libreadline6 package will be installed.

I finally have:
R scripting front-end version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)